# Channel Form javascript error when using Bootstrap

Tags: safecracker, javascript, bootstrap

I'm using Channel Form (Safecracker) on a site which is using Bootstrap.

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

in this script: ACT=10&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,button,dialog,datepicker&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=underscore,cp/date&v=1412459416&use_live_url=y

It happens even if I create form for channel that does not have any fields at all (did that for testing)

Have anyone else experienced similar issue and have a solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens with duplicate jquery files. You can add either of these parameters

```
include_jquery="no"
```

```
include_assets="no"
```

Comment: Thank you! I use `include_jquery="no"` already, but haven't been aware of  `include_assets="no"`. I think that should do the trick. Will let you know.

Comment: For anyone interested, the error was originated by `overlay.js`. I ended up commenting out line that adds it in `Channel_form_lib.php`, as I needed to included assets for most of the fieldtypes.